# What get_directory_property really does?

Tags: cmake, scope

I was searching for how to detect if current scope has a parent in CMake, and one solution mentioned was using `get_directory_property`.

Can someone please explain about usage of `get_directory_property`?

Comment: sorry i am new to this, so i couldn't get what explained in the documentation.

Comment: it get's one of [directory properties](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-properties.7.html#properties-on-directories). What exactly is unclear to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When CMake runs, it populates several properties (essentially meta-data) for the targets, directories, source files it interacts with. There are even global properties defined for the current CMake execution. The full, extensive list of properties is in the CMake [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-properties.7.html). Target have the *most* properties by far, but in your case, you are interested in the **directory** properties [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-properties.7.html#properties-on-directories).

CMake provides `get_*` functions allowing us to retrieve properties that have been defined already:

- [`get_directory_property()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/get_directory_property.html): Use this to retrieve a property about a particular ***directory***, a directory that has already been traversed by CMake.
- [`get_target_property()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/get_target_property.html): Use this to retrieve a property associated with particular ***target***. The target must already be defined earlier in the CMake configuration, or CMake must be aware of it.
- [`get_property()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/get_property.html#command:get_property): A command you can use to get **any** type of property, but you must specify *what* type (e.g. `GLOBAL`, `DIRECTORY`, `TARGET`, etc.)

To find out if the current CMake scope has a parent scope, we can find this information in the directory property [`PARENT_DIRECTORY`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_dir/PARENT_DIRECTORY.html). This will tell us which directory is the *parent* of the current source directory:

```
get_directory_property(MY_DIRECTORY_PARENT PARENT_DIRECTORY)
```